# NPM Install Failed due to permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions

I am unable to install this [dashpay](https://github.com/dashpay/bitcore-node-dash). It said permission error. I tried to install with @root, but same error.

Currently I'm using DigitalOcean with 8GM RAM.

Please refer picture below, using `-g` and without.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should install it globally using `npm install -g bitcore-node-dash`. note the `-g`

Comment: I have try added `-g` into the command. But still the same. You may check updated thread.